# Remove elements of a list if is in another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists with some number combinations and I would like to remove the element of a list is in the other list.

I mean, lists could be:

```py
X = [1, 2, 3, 128, 129, 134, 135, 136, 145, 146, 156, 164, 234, 235, 236, 245, 246, 266, 345]
Y = [12, 16, 26, 126]
```

So I would like to delete from the first list all the elements that include any element of the second list, so we would remove all items that contain '12', '16', '26' or '126'.

Ending up with a list compounded by

```py
[1, 2, 3, 134, 135, 136, 145, 146, 156, 234, 235, 236, 245, 246, 256, 345]
```

Greetings and thanks in advance

Comment: Should `12` cause `312` to be removed? what about `4123`?

Comment: `256` doesn't appear in the initial `X`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
str_y = list(map(str, Y))

X = [e for e in X if all(y not in str(e) for y in str_y)]
X
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 134, 135, 136, 145, 146, 156, 234, 235, 236, 245, 246, 345]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
Y=[str(i) for i in Y]
[i for i in X if not any(str(i).__contains__(j) for j in Y)]
# [1, 2, 3, 134, 135, 136, 145, 146, 156, 234, 235, 236, 245, 246, 345]
```

Comment: you could use __ contains __ rather than startswith to search the entire string

Comment: @tomgalpin `'226'.__contains__('26')` will return `True`. But we shouldn't add `226` according to OP's constraints. `startswith` is the way to go.

Comment: Because the OP doesnt want the element to exists anywhere else in the second element, not just at the start. Your answer doesnt work

Comment: @tomgalpin So he wants to remove even `'226'` too? If that's the case then I'm wrong

Comment: "So we would remove all items that contain '12', '16', '26' or '126' "

Comment: @tomgalpin Looks like I misunderstood the question. Thanks for pointing out. ;) editing it

Comment: i appreciate its kinda hard to understand, but given a different answer which was accepted does remove 226, id say so

Comment: @tomgalpin OP should add good [mcve] which should cover all edge cases. It was hard for me to understand what OP wanted. :P